# Drupal 7 all Users of one role need to be accessible from other role

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce, drupal-permissions, drupal-roles

We are using Drupal Commerce in our website.

We have multiple roles in this website ex. Customer, Customer representative, Content editor and Admin.

Users with "Customer" roles will be allowed to purchase product and make orders, Edit profile.
Users with "Customer representative" roles will be allowed to manage all users that are having "Customer" role. Which will include profile edit of any customer, edit customer's orders etc.

We are not sure how to make this functionality working with Drupal7 and Workbench module.

Any suggestions/ideas?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions for allowing "sub-admin" users to manage other users based on the target user\'s role.

The module defines new permissions to control access to edit/delete users - more specific than Drupal Core\'s all-or-nothing 'administer users'. It also provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.

https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole